# TBxml parsing with tableview along string seperator

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uilabel, tbxml

I'm parsing an xml file from an url and it displays the content correctly.here is my xml file

```
<gold>
<price>
<title>22 K Gold - SGD $69.50</title>
</price>
<price>
<title>24 K Gold - SGD $62.50</title>
</price>
</gold>
```

now its displays each content in cell like the image below

[image]

Now i need to display 22kgold in a cell and SGD $69.50 in a cell.and also the next element same.And also to print these values in two labels.

here is my code in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.p41tech.com/img/application/android/server/kamala/goldprice.xml"]];
    tbxml = [[TBXML alloc]initWithXMLData:xmlData];


    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    if (root)
    {
        TBXMLElement * elem_PLANT = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"price" parentElement:root];

        while (elem_PLANT !=nil)
        {
            TBXMLElement * elem_BOTANICAL = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:elem_PLANT];
            NSString *botanicalName = [TBXML textForElement:elem_BOTANICAL];
            [tableArray addObject:botanicalName];
            elem_PLANT = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"price" searchFromElement:elem_PLANT];
        }      
    }

    label1.text=@"%@",botanicalName;
    label2.text=@"%@",elem_PLANT;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];   
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

My label contents are not displayed and i need to separate string in each cell by '-'.Please guide me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", botanicalName];
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", elem_PLANT];
```

otherwise you were assigning the string "%@" into the labels, and ignoring `botanicalName` and `elem_PLANT`.

To separate the rows into two parts, you can use the following inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
NSArray *parts = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
NSString *item = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *price = [parts objectAtIndex:1];
```

You can then either:

1. Use one of the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, or `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` cell styles, and assign the `item` and `price` variables to the `cell.textLabel.text` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text` properties, or
2. you could add a custom cell view, and assign them to your own labels within that view.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the point of the two labels was, as it looks as though they're only going to display the last item in the list. Are they for debugging?  You would probably need to use textForElement with elem_PLANT to get a text value out of it.

Comment: i tried by using this code elem_PLANT = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"price" searchFromElement:elem_PLANT]; 
            NSString *plant=[TBXML textForElement:elem_PLANT];
but still facing same issue..

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, that would be expected behaviour. At that point (after the loop), elem_PLANT must, by definition, be nil, so calling textForElement: with it is likely to crash, or at least be blank.  If this is just for debugging, why not just remove the code; if not, figure out what you're really trying to do, then go about that. Cheers, Marty.